# VBA How to validate cells when using specific string?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a excel sheet, which uses a macro to make some validation. I am trying to verify all rows (paragraphs) in “Table (T)/ Line (L)” column are set to “T” for table and all other rows (paragraphs) use the L option. This column “Table (T)/ Line (L)” uses a list validation. So if the current cell in “Text Block Row” column is empty, the value in the its corresponding cell in “Table (T)/ Line (L)” column must be "L" . If the value is "T" and the "Text Block Row" cell is empty, a msgbox must appear:
For the table paragraph in row 7 is no “Text Block Row” defined.
Here is a screenshot and my code I`ve done till now:

http://prntscr.com/juuu20

http://prntscr.com/juwy3k-  The wrong macro msgbox

```
Sub checkcolumns()

Dim rngcheck As Range
Dim rngcheck2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Set rngcheck = Range("B4:B6")
Set rngcheck2 = Range("C4:C6")

 i = 0

For Each cell In rngcheck

For Each cell2 In rngcheck2

    i = i + 1

    j = j & cell.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine
    d = d & cell2.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine

  If IsEmpty(cell) Then

  If cell2.Value = "L" Then
  mess = mess & vbCrLf & "For the line paragraph in row:" & vbNewLine & d + "no “Text Block Row” can be defined"

  'For the table paragraph in row 7 is no “Text Block Row” defined
      End If

    Else

  cell2.Value = "T"
  mess = mess & vbCrLf & "For the table paragraph in row:" & vbNewLine & j + "is no “Text Block Row” defined"
 End If

      Next cell2
  Next cell

  If mess <> "" Then MsgBox mess

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see a question in there.

Comment: I think now the title is better

Comment: Yes that's a better title, but you need to ask a specific question. Does your code error, not do as intended etc.

Comment: @SJR, do you have an idea what can be improved in this code?

Comment: The error is I think due to the second loop

Comment: You haven't mentioned an error. If you are getting an error, tell us the error message and which line errors.

Comment: There is no error but the wrong output, I will post the link.

Comment: Hris, at a quick glance it appears you are not hitting your next `cell`.  You call `Next cell2` which will loop back to your `For Each`; this is causing your `cell` value to remain the same and not move down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it very difficult to answer this question because you are not spelling out your problem precisely. This is my best guess.

```
Sub checkcolumns()

Dim rngcheck As Range
Dim rngcheck2 As Range
Dim cell As Range, j As String, d As String, mess As String

Set rngcheck = Range("B4:B6")
Set rngcheck2 = Range("C4:C6")

For Each cell In rngcheck
    j = j & cell.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine
    d = d & cell.Offset(, 1).Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        If cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "L" Then
            mess = mess & vbCrLf & "For the line paragraph in row:" & vbNewLine & d & "no “Text Block Row” can be defined"
            'For the table paragraph in row 7 is no “Text Block Row” defined
        ElseIf cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "T" Then
            mess = mess & vbCrLf & "For the table paragraph in row:" & vbNewLine & j & "is no “Text Block Row” defined"
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If mess <> "" Then MsgBox mess

End Sub
```

Comment: This answer is fine but  the msgbox http://prntscr.com/juxiee shows an error in C4 but this cell is ok. So the error must be applied only for C5 and C6 which have "L" value

Comment: But with one for loop it`s actually a lot better

Comment: Try stepping through the code to see what's going on. I don't know which cells are C4/5/6.

Comment: The C4/5/6 cells are the cell.offsets. I found out that in the output: http://prntscr.com/juxqh0 that the msg "no “Text Block Row” can be defined" is applied to the wrong cell- C3 and C4 which have "T" value and are fine

Comment: I changed the range to B3:C3 just to see if the first msg will be output and it is all right

Comment: But the second message is applied to the wrong cells-C3 and C4